# Use pweight with confidence intervals and store in a matrix

Tags: stata, survey

I am calculating a lot of means on survey-data, where I have to use proportional weights.

Unfortunately, `weights` are not allowed with the command `ci`. I could use the `mean` command but I need to have the results stored, so I subsequently can put them into a matrix.

My loop-code looks like this:

```
local i = 1
foreach var of varlist hinst1 - hinst34 {
  ci varname if `var'==1  
  mat matname[`i',1]=r(mean)
  mat matname[`i',1]=r(lb)  
  mat matname[`i',1]=r(ub)  
  local ++i

}
```

It is possible to use `aweights` but I need `pweights`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stata's `nhanes2f` toy dataset as an example:

```
webuse nhanes2f, clear
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)
```

The `svy` prefix can be used as follows:

```
matrix A = J(3,3,.)

local i = 1

foreach var of varlist sex race region {
  svy: mean age if `var'==1 
  matrix res = r(table)
  matrix A[1,`i'] = res[1, 1]
  matrix A[2,`i'] = res[5, 1]
  matrix A[3,`i'] = res[6, 1]  
  local ++i
}

matrix list A

A[3,3]
           c1         c2         c3
r1  41.898222  42.508557  43.133186
r2  41.206209  41.852839  42.034576
r3  42.590235  43.164274  44.231796
```